# Running a Bash Script Continuously Across Multiple Servers (Local, Jumpbox and Dev server)

Tags: node.js, bash, docker

I wrote a bash script to build a docker container (a NODE JS app) at the end so that the application runs on a DEV server. The thing is that the bash script has to be run in stages across multiple servers i.e., we need to build the docker container in local, ssh to a jump box and rsync it over there and then rsync it from the jumpbox to the dev server and then ssh to it again (if this process is done manually).

If you look at step 5 in the BASH script below, the rsync gets completed and the script runs to SSH to the jumpbox server, however, the script stops over there and I am just logged in to the jumpbox.

Could someone let me know what is wrong with this bash script and how should I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Best,
R

```
#!/bin/bash

#This script allows users to deploy the application with minimal work

echo -n "Shall we begin the deployment process? Are you ready to rule the world with QA Hero's next version? `\n` If you are, then type YES and press [ENTER]?: "
read begin

echo "Wohoooo! You did the right thing! We are now ready to roll and you can actually see your terminal scroll! Lol, what a troll!"

echo -n "Yo mate! Can you enter your enumber and press [ENTER]?: "
read enumber

docker build --build-arg NODE_ENV=staging -t course-hero-x -f Dockerfile .

echo "The file has been built! Step 1 completed"

termdown 3

echo "BOOM! Get ready for step 2."

docker save -o course-hero.tar course-hero-x

termdown 3

echo "BOOM! Get ready for step 3."

rsync -avzh --progress --stats course-hero.tar `echo ${enumber}`@10.188.129.25:/home/`echo ${enumber}`

termdown 3

echo "BOOM! Get ready for step 4."

ssh `echo ${enumber}`@10.188.129.25

termdown 3

echo "BOOM! Get ready for step 5."

ls -la

termdown 3

echo "BOOM! Get ready for step 6."

if ["$enumber" == "e30157" || "$enumber" == "E30167"]; then
    rsync -avzh --progress --stats course-hero.tar `echo ${enumber^^}`@10.80.63.65:/home/eh7/`echo ${enumber^^}`
elif ["$enumber" == "e32398" || "$enumber" == "E32398"]; then
    rsync -avzh --progress --stats course-hero.tar `echo ${enumber^^}`@10.80.63.65:/home/eh8/`echo ${enumber^^}`
else
    echo "You cannot access this system."
fi    

termdown 3

echo "BOOM! Get ready for step 7."

ssh `echo ${enumber^^}`@10.80.63.65

echo "BOOM! Get ready for step 8."

ls -la

echo "BOOM! Get ready for step 9."

sudo docker load -i course-hero.tar

termdown 3

echo "BOOM! Get ready for step 10."

sudo docker ps

termdown 3

echo "BOOM! Get ready for step 11."

sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -a -q)

termdown 3

echo "BOOM! Get ready for step 12."

sudo docker rm $(sudo docker ps -a -q)

termdown 3

echo "BOOM! Get ready for step 13."

sudo docker load -i course-hero.tar

termdown 3

echo "BOOM! Get ready for step 14."

sudo docker run -d -e TZ=Australia/Melbourne --net=courseHero -p 0.0.0.0:80:3000 course-hero-x

echo "QA Hero is up and running. Go to http://cohero-dev.rmit.edu.au to checkout the latest version!"

termdown 3

echo "Step 15 completed! We are done here! See you next time homey!"
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or as close as possible.

Comment: I don't understand the problem description. Does the script do something strange when running `ls -la`? And what is `termdown`?

Comment: You might consider some higher-level tools rather than building this entirely by hand.  If you run a Docker registry your isolated server can reach, you can `docker push` to it rather than manually copying the image around; and any of the popular configuration management tools (Chef, Salt Stack, Ansible) can manage the task of running commands or even updating Docker containers on remote hosts for you.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've open an ssh session to the other box your local script stops because it's waiting for the ssh session to end. You're just left sitting at a command prompt on the remote box.

It looks like what you're intending to have happen is the commands following your ssh run on the remote box. To send the commands to the remote machine redirect them:

```
ssh ${enumber}@10.188.129.25 <<'ENDSSH'
# series of commands to 
# run on remote host
ENDSSH
```

Consider running your script through [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) — you've got several problems with it beyond the one you asked about.